# How to handle stackoverflow to a disk kind of situation for Distributed caching using hazelcast?

Tags: hazelcast

I am implementing distributed caching using hazelcast for one of my product. Kindly let us know how to to handle stackoverflow to a disk, when it exceeds the given RAM kind of situation?

Comment: Do you mean OVERFLOW to disk?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure map persistence and implement a [MapStore](http://www.hazelcast.com/docs/2.0/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/MapStore.html) that stores items to disk. Note that Hazelcast has no feature like persisting only items those exceeding some amount of heap, instead Hazelcast persists all items in memory to storage.

**Also note that Hazelcast persistence requires central storage; all nodes should access and write to / read from same storage (disk, database etc.)**

To limit number of items to be stored in memory, you should configure eviction properties; like TTL, max-idle, max-size, eviction-policy etc.

[Hazelcast MapPersistence](http://www.hazelcast.com/docs/2.0/manual/single_html/#MapPersistence)

[Hazelcast Eviction](http://www.hazelcast.com/docs/2.0/manual/single_html/#MapEviction)